# Can I delete multiple of nth rows in a single query from a table in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to delete multiple of 4 from my table which have thousands of record. How can I do it?

```
Ex:-
Table1
1 a
2 b
3 c
4 d
5 e
6 f
7 g
8 h
9 i
```

I want to delete every 4th row.

I don't want to use a loop or cursor.

Answer (score 3):

```
Delete A from
(
Select *,Row_Number() Over(Order By Id) as RN from TableA
) A
where RN%4=0
```

[SQL Fiddle Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/40580/5)

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
delete from table_name where (col1 % 4) = 0
```

Comment: Assuming from OP's example, that the "n"-th row as a value of "n" in the first column and the first column is a continuous series of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `CTE`.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t.rowfield) AS rank
       FROM Table1 t) 
SELECT rowfield, fielda 
FROM cte
WHERE rank%4 != 0
```

Output

```
rowfield fielda
1        a
2        b
3        c
5        e
6        f
7        g
9        i
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c9540b/13/0

Once you are happy with the output use `DELETE FROM`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DECLARE @nvalToDelete varchar(100)='4,7,3,8,9'-- just give values to delete from table 

DECLARE @temp TABLE 
  ( 
     valtodelete VARCHAR(100) 
  ) 
DECLARE @Deletetemp TABLE 
  ( 
     valtodelete INT 
  ) 

INSERT INTO @temp 
SELECT @nvalToDelete 

INSERT INTO @Deletetemp 
SELECT split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(1000)') AS valToDelete 
FROM   (SELECT Cast('<S>' + Replace(valtodelete, ',', '</S><S>') 
                    + '</S>' AS XML) AS valToDelete 
        FROM   @temp) AS A 
       CROSS apply valtodelete.nodes('/S') AS Split(a) 


DECLARE @Table1 TABLE 
(
ID INT,
val varchar(10)
)
INSERT INTO @Table1
SELECT 1,'a' UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'b' UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'c' UNION ALL
SELECT 4,'d' UNION ALL
SELECT 5,'e' UNION ALL
SELECT 6,'f' UNION ALL
SELECT 7,'g' UNION ALL
SELECT 8,'h' UNION ALL
SELECT 9,'i' 

SELECT * 
FROM   @Table1; 

WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT *, 
                RN = Row_number() 
                       OVER ( 
                         ORDER BY id ) 
         FROM   @Table1) 
DELETE FROM @Table1 
WHERE  id IN(SELECT id  FROM   cte 
             WHERE  rn IN (SELECT CASt(valToDelete AS INT) FROM @Deletetemp) 
)
SELECT * 
FROM   @Table1
```

Comment: it deletes only one row

Comment: it can deletes n values given

Answer (score 0):

This can use an index if one exists and uses [numbers table](http://dataeducation.com/you-require-a-numbers-table/)

```
;with cte
as
(select n from numbers
where n%4=0
)
delete t
from table1 t
join
cte c
on c.n=t.id
```